# Select layer in Photoshop with layer effects

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, photoshop-effects, selections, marquee-tool

I need a way to get at the dimensions of a Photoshop layer with their layer effects. All methods I can find (such as command/control-clicking the layer thumbnail) only select the base layer and never include their effects.

Is there a way to select/marquee the Photoshop layer *plus* its effects (without manually adjusting the selection using Expand) or to at least get the size of the layer *plus* its effects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to make the effects their own layer, or convert the object to a smart object.

**Smart Object**(recommended non-destructive)

Right click on the layer and convert it to a smart object.  It should account for the effects in your bounding box and dimensions.

OR

**Effect Layers**

Select the object and Go to Layer -> Layer Style -> Create Layer

This will convert all the effects into their respective layers.  Then you can group and it will account for those effects.

Answer (score 2):

- New layer (<kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Option/Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>)
- Merge Visible  (<kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Option/Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>)
- Command/Ctrl click the tumbnail
- Delete the new layer if necessary

You could also use the `Create Layer` option by Control/Right-clicking the `fx` icon next to the layer name in the **Layer Panel**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate the layer and create a new empty layer. Hold both layers and merge them (duplicated one and empty one) then hit ctrl+t. You will see the dimensions in the info panel (window -> info)

Answer (score 0):

Please, check out this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3qD65rZn3aM

Comment: Hi Raptor, could you please explain a bit more what we'll find behind the link you provide and why it answers the question? That way, your answer is still of value in case the link breaks at a later time. Link rot is the main reason we really dislike link-only answers here. Thanks!